# C# JavaScriptSerializer and DateTime.MinValue crossing timezones

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

Given that I have a client and a server, and a class like this:

Client side: (TimeZone: UTC -8)

```
class Foo {
      public int a;
      public DateTime MyTime { get; set; }
    }

var serialized = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new Foo { a = 1 });
// Send serialized to server
```

Server side: (TimeZone UTC-4)

```
// Receive JSON
var deserialized = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Foo>(serialized);
if (deserialized.MyTime == DateTime.MinValue) {
  // dostuff
}
```

My problem here is that `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(foo)`, does `MyTime.MinValue.ToUniversalTime()` which gives me **1. january 0001 08:00:00**. Next when I deserialize on the server side, it sees 8 hours over `DateTime.MinValue` and the if test fails. I also cannot do to localtime, because the server and client are not in the same timezone, so localtime would give me **1. january 0001 04:00:00**.

In the end of this I have to questions:

1. What is the best way to handle this given that
   `JavaScriptSerializer()` does the call `.ToUniversalTime()`. My
   current approach is to just check a timerange around year 0.
2. Given that we have `DateTime.MinValue`, should one not expect this value to always be exactly that. Should not the `DateTime.MinValue.ToUniversalTime()` be equal to `DateTime.MinValue`? Basically I am asking if there should be an explicit if check looking for `DateTime.MinValue` in all conversion routines.

Thanks.

JavaScriptSerializer: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx 
DateTime: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: Also, for both performance-reasons and resolution of problems like this, it's advisable to use Newtonsoft.Json instead of JavascriptSerializer.

Comment: Are you using `DateTime.MinValue` as a replacement to `null`? If yes, why not using `public DateTime? MyTime` and setting it to null instead of bothering with MinValue?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass them around as strings instead of DateTimes. `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ` will make it culture-neutral and cast it to UTC, which will ignore all time zones. This is used in the C# [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) as code `u`.

Comment: Thanks krillgar, its a good idea if I was always in control of the client application. The problem is that I want to be able to let others integrate with the server, and therefore I cannot assume they will adhere to this.

Comment: This really does need to become more common practice. I remember the first time that I ran into problems with DateTime conversions was just in C# code. I was using a handheld Windows CE device through a Web Service. Between the device, the service, and the database, I was winding up about 11 hours off because each section of the code was assuming that I was converting partially from a UTC time. It was a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`. It looks like the serializer serializes the struct as follows:

```
{"a":1,"MyTime":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"}
```

This means that this string can be deserialized by either a `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` field on the server side. It looks like both of those deserialize the above string to midnight, so I'm assuming that the deserializer interprets the number as a +00:00 offset as it comes off the wire.